# Themes - Change bubbles to checkboxes?

Tags: interface, add-on, theme

In blenders default themes, the toggles are represented by checkmarks with colored backgrounds. In my custom theme, I only have bubbles without any checkmarks.

Where is the setting I can change to make my custom theme into checkmark boxes instead of bubbles?

Bubbles:

[image: Bubbles]

Checkboxes:

[image: Checkboxes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Edit > Preferences > Themes > Interface > Option* change the *Alpha* value for the *Item* color.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow I can even set colored checkmarks thanks to this, wonderful!